# What's the tool used to create geometry illustration graphics on wikipedia

Tags: wikipedia

When I read articles about geometry/graphics on wikipedia, I see some very clean illustration graphics, for example:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Is there any way to create graphics like this easily?

[edit] I got 3 votes for close this topic when it was viewed 6 times. Ok, let me give more background here:
I'm a programmer mainly for CAD tools. I need to check wikipedia when I have problems for some basic geometry calculation. So I read articles which includes some clean geometry illustration graphics.

I know that it's easy to create graphics like this in a CAD tool. But I don't think people will spend more than US$1000 to buy a CAD tool just in order to draw graphics like this.

Actually my favorite illustration tool is Microsoft PowerPoint. I used it a lot to help me analysis. It's really easy for me to quickly draw some illustrations like this. But today I got some issues. I want to draw 3 lines and make their length fixed, then drag the end points of them to verify my algorithm. The requirement is: when I drag the end points, the length of the 3 lines should be fixed, or in future I can adjust it accurately(I mean, with a specific number). I tried PowerPoint for a while, but cannot make it. Then I posted this question to stackoverflow, my favorite Q&A community. I also has some contributions to this community.

Why 50% of your guys viewed this question and vote for close?

Comment: The link from wikipedia for the last graphics is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Orthogonal_circle.svg. (In case you need it.)

Comment: I'm wandering why my question was viewed 4 times, but got 2 votes for close. Looks like AD? It seems that people reading this article are different with people from programming community.

Comment: got 3 votes for close when viewed 6 times? anyone can tell me why?

Comment: Too many perfectly valid, useful, and in accordance with the rules, questions are just closed by people who usually don't understand the problem beyond the question at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked for free alternatives to http://www.geometryexpressions.com/ and found that [Interactive Geometry Software Cinderella](http://www.cinderella.de/tiki-index.php) has free version for Windows, Mac OS X and Linux (with JVM). No export to SVG, not too perfect...

Comment: Just took a look at the screenshot of geometryexpressions, looks good. Thanks a lot for your comments. I'm installing Java plugin in order to play Cinderella demos.

Comment: played geometryexpressions for a while, feature rich, powerful, excellent job, and expensive.

Comment: Oh, just got this list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_geometry_software A lot of time is necessary to explore these instruments ;)

Answer (score 3):

I looked at the meta data for the creator's [images](https://toolserver.org/~daniel/WikiSense/Gallery.php?wikifam=commons.wikimedia.org&wikilang=en&order=-img_timestamp&img_user_text=WillowW&max=25&ofs=0&max=250)

SVG comments indicate that they were created by [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/).

However, this may simply be the tool he used for final post-processing, not for creating the original images.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. I'll install inkscape and see if it's what I want.

Comment: tried inkscape for a while, it's very easy to use and with excellent flexibility, while not easy to make "serious" graphics.

Answer (score 2):

I found this free tool [GeoGebra](http://www.geogebra.org). Which is very popular in education, and is excellent. You need Java to run it.

What's GeoGebra:

> Free mathematics software for learning and teaching
>
> - Interactive graphics, algebra and spreadsheet
> - From elementary school to university level
> - Free learning materials